# what is the git command so as to open a repository

Tags: git

I'm learning Git using Git Extension which provide graphical user interface.

But I have to do a command that I have not found in Git Extension. ( I want to do `git checkout -- myFile` so as to revert it).

So I was going to try with command line... However when i launch Git Bash, I cannot open the repository I am working on.  I have not found any command that resemble to this ( git-open or something like that)

Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: You might want to read (part of) a Linux tutorial such as [this one](http://tldp.org/LDP/gs/node5.html) for basic Bash usage, even if you're using Git on Windows. Skip the part about logging in.

Comment: @FredFoo 7 years later, I only use git on the command line now. And I also have totally given up with Windows also...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to "open" your repository, just `cd` to the directory.

Answer (score 2):

From GitExtension, open your repository, then you can open git bash and do what you want.

Or, start git bash, then cd to the directory where your code is (at the top level), but, I find it easier to just start with GitExtension so I don't have to think about what I had typed as the top of my src.